# Nginx dynamic proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, proxypass

I'm trying to configure nginx to proxy when `$1` is the path to a unix socket and $2 the uri :

- `/user/<username>` => `/tmp/<username>/socket.sock /`
- `/user/<username>/a` => `/tmp/<username>/socket.sock /a`
- `/user/<username>/a/b` => `/tmp/<username>/socket.sock /a/b`

`location ~/user/(.+)/(.*)$ {
    proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/$1/socket.sock:/$2

}`

Of course it doesn't work for the third example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found :

```
location ~/user/(\d+)/(.*)$ {
    proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/$1/socket.sock:/$2
}
```